# Error when trying to delete cell to tableView

Tags: swift, swift5

When I try to delete a cell I get this error:

> Thread 1: "Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0. The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (4) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (4), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out). Table view: <UITableView: 0x7fa813016a00; frame = (0 0; 375 667); clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600000e7ca50>; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000083f00>; contentOffset: {0, -116}; contentSize: {375, 2461.5}; adjustedContentInset: {116, 0, 0, 0}; dataSource: <tableRemove.CustomViewController: 0x7fa817d04280>>"

Full implementation of work with tableView looks like this:

```
    extension CustomViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return itemList[section].itemToList.count
        
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        model[section].nameItem
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath)
        let text = model[indexPath.section].itemToList[indexPath.row].nameFood
        cell.textLabel?.text =  text
        return cell
    }
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return itemList.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        true
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
        model.swapAt(sourceIndexPath.row, destinationIndexPath.row)
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell.EditingStyle {
        return .delete
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            tableView.beginUpdates()
            model[indexPath.section].itemToList.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
            tableView.endUpdates()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that some of your methods depend on itemList but others depend on model.

Comment: Avoid multiple source of truth